# Magento 2: Is there a way to return custom json response from REST API without building a data interface?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json, webapi

I have a few custom REST API interfaces on my module & they all need to return a standard json response (different on each).
After a little research, I realized that I can't do something like `@return object` & that `echo json_encode($res);die;` is discouraged & that I can build a custom data interface with a getter method for every field.
For my specific needs, it'll require very long files with tons of getter methods (I have to return a specific structure of fields as json).

---

Is there a way to build this data interface without creating a method for every field in the response?
e.g. something that I can load with an array/object or even a json encoded string & it'll just reply with that without any change.
*I know that I can `return json_encode(...);` & define the return type as a string, but it's wrapping it with quotes ("{...}") & escapes & I don't want it that way.

---

-- Any Idea?